# Populate a form table using data from a myMsql db (via Java lists)

Tags: javascript, json, rest, groovy, bonita

I'm using **Bonita BPM 7.3** for developing a simple software. Currently, I'm focusing on a single process, about document requests. The user choose a document from a table, then he/she compiles it or download it. *The problem:* I'm not able to populate the table. the documents are loaded from a MySQL database, via the provided connector. The table remains blank.  I think the problem is in managing the list variable in the user form. Other details:

- I tested the connector and it's working (It returned me the data)
- I tried many solutions via REST API, no success
- I used both a fake list initialized via groovy script and the "real one", no   success
- I have read every question here about similar problems
- I've also bought a Bonita BPM guide but it's not helpful about this
- I have looked for a solution everywhere, also in the Bonita documentation, video guides etc.

What I would like: A simple yet detailed explanation on how to display lists content in a table on a form.
Fell free to ask more details, any help will be welcome

Comment: Please add the code you have so far. To clarify, by "table" do you mean an HTML table, or a MySQL table? I suspect the former, but I think you've mixed contexts.

Comment: Sorry my description was not detailed enogh, yes I meant a widget table in a form, not a MySQL table. There's little code to show: "../{{context.stringBV_ref.link}}" is the REST API call I use in the form to access the business variable, with no success

Comment: How do you store the documents list? Is "stringBV" a process variable, a business variable or a document variable?

Comment: If you can share your process and BDM by exporting them a .bos file that can also be helpful to understand your use case.